# How to provide json text file to client side ajax request on node.js server

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm running a simple node.js web app on an aws ubuntu server. I have some json data from an api that I have stored locally on the ubuntu server in a text file called `data.json`.

I simply want to load that data from the json file via an AJAX call and render it on the client side html.

Here is my project directory structure:

```
    MyApp
      server.js
      index.html
      data.json
```

This client-side code works in Webstorm and locally, but on my live server returns an error (looks like it's returning an html error file instead of json which explains the parsing error, but doesn't solve how to get this data).

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $.ajax({
             url: "/data/data.json",
             method: "GET",
             dataType: "json",
             error: function() {
                  console.log("error");
             },
             success: function(data) {
                  console.log(data);
             }
        });
  });
</script>
```

I think I need to serve this json file from within node so I can make an HTTP GET request from the client side, but don't understand how it all goes together. Can someone please help provide an example?

Edit: Node server.js code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);

var router = express.Router();

router.use(function (req, res, next) {
    console.log("/" + req.method);
    next();
});

router.get("/",function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.use("/",router);

app.use("*",function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.use('/data', express.static('public'));

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Server is running on port 3000...');
```

Comment: Thanks, do you have an example of what that looks like? I write that in my server.js node file? How is that called from the front end?

Comment: Yes, express. Do I need 'serve-static' or what? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to put `*.json` files into sub folder. Than on the server side give static access to that folder.

Example:
put all `*.json` files inside `./public` folder

```
// server.js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use('/data', express.static('public'))
...
```

Client side:

```
$.get( "/data/my-file.json", function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

Comment: It's loading an html file when I do this instead of my data.json. Then errors since can't parse the '<'.  I'm using routes in my node server.js file too.

Comment: put app.use before routes

Comment: I updated my question to include my server.js node code.

Comment: Just move the line   app.use('/data', express.static('public')) - before line app.use("/",router);   The order is important!